# (Insect Wing Modeling) Bridge Edge Loops+ Fusing Objects

Tags: modeling, mesh

I already did this question in another forum, but I actually couldn't understand the answers. I am trying to model a insect wing follow the techniques of this video by Damien Monteillard:
https://youtu.be/vYffs8n9IJI

Specifically, between times **5:12** to **6:07** Damien uses an eight-sided circle to shape the "bones" that support the wing.He doubles the circle several times to bridge the other parallel points and use the bridge tool to connect two edge loops , but my real question is: how did he connect the "parallel bones" to the "bridge bones" using the bridge tool non-destructively to the polygon?

I've fast-forwarded and replayed the video numerous times, but it looks like the part where it should be making connections has been cut off. This has been on my mind for a good few months (?) and I'm almost getting crazy thinking about it.
If anyone out there can/know how to help me, I will be very grateful

Thanks in advance <3

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please show some close-up screenshots of your own mesh so that we can see what part of the modeling you're asking about?

Comment: Hello moonboots I'll link the images here, but they're not with good quality. I hope it helps: https://photos.app.goo.gl/jqcAjfU848b45K2CA https://photos.app.goo.gl/eWwQ8EFqxR8Kgw7L8

Comment: hello show some screenshots of your own mesh so that we understand what kind of operation you need

Answer (score 1):

Is it the kind of bridge you're looking for?

[image]

[image]

[image]